# Javascript excecute function after 500 ms, but return on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, settimeout

I want to excecute a javascript function after 500ms, but not when a key is pressed, like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.class').keyup(function(Key) {
         setTimeout(function(){
              // excecute this not when any key is pressed
         },500)
    })
})
```

Comment: If a key is down at the time your function is supposed to run (after 500ms), do you want to cancel it entirely, or do you want to wait until no keys are pressed and execute it then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to store timeout identifier somewhere and clear it if 500ms has not yet passed during the next keyup event. It's convenient to save this id in data property of the related input:

```js
$('.class').keyup(function (Key) {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        alert('pressed');
    }, 500));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="class" placeholder="Type something">
```

Comment: Nice _idea_ to use `data-` attribute, my upv...I'll start to do like that!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want some code to run after you make a keypress but not if another key is pressed. In that case store the function in a variable and clear it on keypress.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    var timed;

    $('.class').keyup(function(Key) {
         timed = setTimeout(function() {
            //code 
         }, 500);
    });

    $(window).keydown(function() {
         clearTimeout(timed);
    });
});
```

Comment: clearTimeout doesn't work that way. It expects the argument to be a return value of setTimeout